# Cat with new line

Tags: bash

My input file's contents are:

> welcome
>
> welcome1
>
> welcome2

My script is:

```
for groupline in `cat file`
do
        echo $groupline;
done
```

I got the following output:

```
welcome
welcome1
welcome2
```

Why doesn't it print the empty line?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you need to set `IFS` to newline `\n`

```
IFS=$"\n"
for groupline in $(cat file)
do
        echo "$groupline";
done
```

Or put double quotes. See [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Word-Splitting) for explanation

```
for groupline in "$(cat file)"
do
        echo "$groupline";
done
```

without meddling with IFS, the "proper" way is to use while read loop

```
while read -r line
do
 echo "$line"
done <"file"
```

Comment: +1 for double quotes. It did the trick for me to echo newlines correctly!

Comment: for me : `IFS=$"\n"` = `n` but with `IFS=$'\n'` seems works

Answer (score 1):

Because you're doing it all wrong. You want `while` not `for`, and you want `read`, not `cat`:

```
while read groupline
do
  echo "$groupline"
done < file
```

Comment: yea , this things I know . But I want know why the cat command not giving the actual things to for loop .

Comment: `for` doesn't care about "lines". It only cares about "words", and anything in `$IFS` is used to delimit words. By default it contains `" \t\n"`, which means that newlines are ignored.

Comment: I accept your comment. Not for code. Because I need the code with for only.

Answer (score 1):

[The solution ghostdog74 provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2460377/cat-with-new-line/2460424#2460424) is helpful, but has a flaw.

IFS could not use double quotes (at least in Mac OS X), but can use single quotes like:

```
IFS=$'\n'
```

It's nice but not dash-compatible, maybe this is better:

```
IFS='
'
```

The blank line will be eaten in the following program:

```
IFS='
'
for line in $(cat file)
do
        echo "$line"
done
```

But you can not add double quotes around `$(cat file)`, it will treat the whole file as one single string.

```
for line in "$(cat file)"
```

If want blank line also be processed, using the following

```
while read line
do
    echo "$line"
done < file
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `IFS=$"\n"` and `var=$(cat text.txt)` removes all the "n" characters from the output `echo $var`